# Wordpress JetPack is not working how to solve it?

Tags: error-handling, wordpress, jetpack

My wordpress blog Jetpack is not working its says that error in load.php file and when i solve it my wordpress dashboard start showing blank screen my blog url is https://trustedmonitors.com/

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? Also, if you're getting a white screen that usually means WordPress is hitting a fatal error somewhere. Please [enable WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and post what error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an installation problem. You need to install the Jetpack plugin again on your website. 
You can also check out the link below:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/integrate-jetpack-wordpress-plugin/

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.